# Scroll to anchor with fixed nav bar, nav fixes after scroll too

Tags: jquery, anchor, smooth-scrolling, anchor-scroll

I have a nav bar that fixes to the top of the screen after it scrolls up 160px. I also use a smooth scroll for anchor links that works great if the nav bar is already fixed to the top of the screen, however if the nav bar is in its unfixed state before scrolling up 160px, then the anchor scroll doesn't take into account the 40px buffer I have added.

I want the smooth scroll to scroll to the anchor exactly -40px whether the nav bar is fixed or not.

The two lots of code i'm using are as follows:

1) Smooth Scroll

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
        }, 750);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

2) Fixed Nav Bar

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(function() {
        $(window).resize(function() {
        // responsive nav primary fixed
        if (window.innerWidth > 960) {
            $(window).bind('scroll', function (){ if ($(window).scrollTop() > 160) {$('.nav-primary').addClass('nav-primary-fixed');} else {$('.nav-primary').removeClass('nav-primary-fixed');}});
        } else {}
        // end responsive nav primary fixed
    }) .resize(); // trigger resize event

    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if the navbar has class `nav-primary-fixed`, and then modify the 40 value accordingly …?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have misunderstood the question. The anchor scroll works perfectly if the site has already been scrolled more than 160px and the navbar has 'nav-primary-fixed' assigned. It doesn't align the anchors properly if the site has not been scrolled from the top and the navbar is not fixed yet. So for instance on page load if I click and anchor link it will scroll to the anchor point but the top of the anchor point will be hidden 40px behind the navbar.

If your solution is the right way to move forward I have no idea how to go about coding that into my current code.

Comment: You need those 40px offset only if the navbar is fixed. So check if it is (.hasClass) - and depending on that, subtract those 40px, or don’t.

Comment: Thank you, with a bit of research into `.hasClass` I know have a working solution, i'll update the question with the correct code to mark it as answered, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so with a little help from CBroe in the comments to the question I did some research on `.hasClass` and found some articles that helped me work out the way to do it, the following jQuery code is the amended and now working, as desired, code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if ($(".nav-primary").hasClass("nav-primary-fixed")) {
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
          }, 750);
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
          }, 750);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Great, but you can still shorten it a bit. Look at the if- and else-branch, their code is identical apart from the actual value used. So why not store that value into a variable upfront, and then have the code that was inside if and else only once, using the variable in place of the 40/80 ...

Comment: I have have since added another elseif statement to apply another value for screen widths less than 960px as mobile and tablet weren't aligning the anchor properly either and what I have has fixed it all.

I did try something like that but it didn't work, but then I didn't try it with the exact if, elseif, else statement used in the working code, so maybe if I tinkered about again, I could shorten as you suggest. Thanks again.